# Wrong time/timezone in Spring Boot application on Kubernetes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kubernetes

I have a Spring Boot application that's running on Kubernetes. The image was built with the `spring-boot:build-image` Maven goal.

I pass timezone information to the container in the deployment.yml file using

```
  volumes:
    - name: tz-rome
      hostPath:
        path: /usr/share/zoneinfo/Europe/Rome
  containers:
    - name: ***
      image: ***
      volumeMounts:
        - name: tz-rome
          mountPath: /etc/localtime
```

And when I try to run `date` from the running container, the result is correct:

```
$ date
Fri Jul 23 10:11:54 CEST 2021
```

But the Spring application logs and the timestamps are two hours early (so, in this case, `8:11:54`).

Explicitly passing the JAVA_OPTS with the current time zone in the k8s deployment.yml file like this:

```
env:
  - name: JAVA_OPTS
    value: "-Duser.timezone=CEST"
```

slightly improves the situation, now the timestamps are only one hour early, but it's still not OK, I need the current time.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was easier than I thought.

`CEST` is not a [valid time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), even if it's present in the `date` command output. By using `Europe/Rome`, everything now works.